# Variable-base column bar graph

Tags: excel, charts

I am trying to get a variable-base column bar graph in Excel. Basically, with reference to the figure below, I have a number of periods. Each period can range from 1 to 5 months. So the various periods do not have the same length. Each period, however, has only one value associated with it that is representative of the entire period.

[image: Figure A]

What I wish to achieve can be seen in the first figure (A), where two characteristics that the graph must have are also highlighted, namely, to consist of columns of varying width, as well as height, and to have the final month of the period placed in the center of the column and not at the bottom right.

I have tried several ways to get this graph with Excel, but all I have been able to get is visible in the second figure (B). Basically, I had to create a second, auxiliary, table by hand from the first, and then generate a normal column chart.

[image: Figure B]

Clearly the result is different from what I wanted, although I came close.

Do you think it is possible, with Excel, to get exactly the chart I need without having to use a second table? Or, alternatively, do you think there are other programs, e.g., Holoviews (Python) to get the expected result?

Comment: This feature is not in the standard set of Excel charts that Microsoft provides.

Comment: Here is a link to an incredibly complicated solution that turns a stacked area chart into a fake bar chart to do what you want.  I don't think I would do this. https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/excel-charts/excel-variable-width-column-chart.html

Comment: Well, quite complicated, but I might write a Python program using Win32com to automate most of the work... Thank you.